# "How is/are" (subject)?

Tags: plural-forms, comparison

Which of the following are/is correct and why?

1. How is your son and daughter?
2. How are your son and daughter?
3. How is your son and your daughter?
4. How are your son and your daughter?

My fundamental question is regarding the correct usage of the verb (whether plural or singular). The above statements are just the example of where I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using phrases with

> **your** son and **your** daughter

would be redundant and not natural other than for emphasis.

> 2) How **are** your son and daughter?

is correct. If you make a reply you can see this:

> My son and daughter **are** fine.